# Initializing an empty local git repository

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

On two different machines, I initialize an empty local git repository -- one using `$ git init` at git bash command line and the other using SourceTree's `File > New > Create Local Repository`.

As can be seen in the two attached images, they are different; for example there is no `hooks` folder in the `.git` directory of the one created with SourceTree.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Neither `hooks` nor `info` folders are necessary for the git repo to work. It could be that SourceTree just doesn't output these by default.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I was doing something terribly wrong as a beginner...

Comment: No problem. By the way, I had a quick search and found http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html which explains what each file/folder in the `.git` folder is/does.